# iPhone SDK - UIWebView embedding a YouTube Video

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, youtube, embed

I am using this to prevent the app from opening the youtube app and instead plays the video whilst staying inside my app.

It works fine and all but it's a bit slow with loading it's date (they're inside a tableview, each cell for about 15 atm~).

The moment when it suddenly loads everything correctly is when this error has been passed into the debugging console:

warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11) /Symbols/System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/YouTubePlugin.webplugin/YouTubePlugin" (file not found).

1. Is it possible that this slows down
   the loading of the uiwebview? (as
   soon as this error's been passed it
   suddenly quickly loads all the
   content).
2. If it doesn't slow anything down is it something my app could get rejected on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is there because the youtube plugin used by your device does not exist in the simulator (indeed, the youtube app is not present in the simulator either). The delay you experience is due to continuous polling of the debugger for info from the original plugin in your device.

Answer (score 2):

you ever find an answer for this? i'm having the same issues

EDIT: this delay is only experienced when debugging on the phone.  the plugin attempts to load and there is a large delay before the youtube view pops up in the webview.  if you unplug the phone from xcode (disabling the remote debugger) it immediately loads the webview

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand your problem. However, the three20 library has a nice youtube control for embedding in applications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll look into that. Thing is that i get that warning whilst everything works like it should. It just really slows down the first launch until that warning is showed.